# How to check that web element is currently not visible, selenium, c#

Tags: c#, selenium

When I check some element is visible I do it like that:

```
public void CheckingVisible {
 Assert.IsTrue(WebElement.Displayed); 
}
```

and it is working

When I try to check is not visible I do like that:

```
public void CheckingNotVisible { Assert.IsFalse(WebElement.Displayed); }
```

and also

```
public void CheckingNotVisible { Assert.IsTrue(!WebElement.Displayed); }
```

But in both cases it does not work. How do I check that the element is currently not visible/presented?

Answer (score 0):

You can use below method, this method will check whether element is visible or not, but before that it will check whether element is available or not.

```
public void CheckVisible() throws Exception
{
    boolean eleche,eleche1 = false;
        try
        {
            eleche = driver.findElements(by.xpath("path")).size()!=0;
        }catch(InvalidSelectorException ISExcep)
        {
            System.out.println("Element Not Available in Page.");
        }
        if(eleche == true)
        {
        try{
                eleche1=driver.findElement(By.xpath("Path")).isDisplayed();
            }catch(org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException NSEE)
            {
                System.out.println("Element Not Visible.");
            }
            if(eleche1 == true)
            {
                System.out.println("\nElement is Visible.");
            }
        }
}
```

Hope my answer will help you.
Thank You,
Ed D, India.

Answer (score 0):

I am more of Java guy, but I hope following code snippet can help you. You need to make sure your element is present prior to checking its visibility.

```
public boolean isElementVisible(String path)
    {
        try {
           WebElement ele = driver.findElements(by.xpath("path")).get(0);
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException e1) {
           //System.out.println("Element Not Visible.");
           return false;
            }
        catch(StaleElementReferenceException e2) {
            //System.out.println("Element Not Visible.");
          return false;
            }
        catch (InvalidSelectorException e3) {
            //System.out.println("Element Not Visible.");
             return false;}


             return ele.Displayed;
    }
```